# difference of two Date instance in hours throws "The end instant must be greater the start" exception

Tags: java, jodatime

I want to find the **difference between two Dates in terms of hours**.

I tried using Joda-Time API:

```
public static long getDateTimeDiffInHours(Date  date1, Date  date2) {
        Interval interval = new Interval(date2.getTime(), date1.getTime());
        Duration period = interval.toDuration();
        return period.getStandardHours();
    }
```

but this throws exception when date1=Mon Jul 01 08:30:00 IST 2019 and date2=Mon Jul 01 12:30:00 IST 2019

```
Exception:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The end instant must be greater the start
```

Please explain to me what is the reason and how I can fix this. I am using Java 8.

Comment: Change the code to check for start and endDate. `if(date1.after(date2)) interval= new Interval(date2.getTime(), date1.getTime()); else interval = new Interval(date1.getTime(), date2.getTime());`

Comment: I tried this it returns 0, but I am expecting 4

Comment: @Silverfang is this exception because minutes are equal?

Comment: It should give you the exact answer. Check whether the duration object is returning the correct values for other formats. `period.getStandardSeconds()` or `period.getStandardMinutes()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the duratin api for the duration ( find the days/ minutes/ hours )

```
Math.abs( Duration.ofMillis(endTime).minusMillis(StartTime).toHours())
```

Edited the answer as the endtime you may pass less than the start time, but always try to check the endtime and start time before trying.